# Update parent instance from child model after_save/after_commit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a review model which is the grandchild of the property model. I'm using a join table (booking) to access the property (the grandparent) from review:

```
#child
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :property, through: :booking
end

#grandparent of review
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews, through: booking
end

#parent of review (join table)
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :property
    belongs_to :review
end
```

Property has an average_rating which should be updated after_save or after_commit (not sure which one) in review as each review has a rating

Currently, I am doing this in the review model:

```
 class Review < ApplicationRecord
     has_one :property, through: :booking
     after_commit :update_average_rating

     private
     def update_average_rating
          property = self.booking.property
          property.average_rating = property.reviews.average(:rating).round(2).to_i
          property.average_rating.save!
     end
end
```

But I keep getting this error:

> "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked>",

I'm obviously doing something wrong as there is a rollback every time I try to update the average_rating in property

Is it possible to update the parent instance from the child model? I've seen other answers on SO suggesting it is. If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Does property have any callbacks that affect review?

Comment: @Joel_Blum there aren't any callbacks in Property, no